# Checking userlevel but it won't work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not the best at php and mysql and i'm still learning however i have this userlevel variable which i define in my session

and if i message it back to myself using

```
 <?php echo"$session->userlevel"; ?>
```

It'll work, it'll tell me that me that my userlevel is "0" which it should be however when i'm using an if statement to check it won't work?

```
 <?php
        if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] = 0) {
            echo "Userlevel 0 was found!";
        }
?>
```

Any though

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_SESSION['userlevel'] = 0)
```

should be

```
if($_SESSION['userlevel'] == 0)
```

Otherwise you don't check, you assign the value `0` to `$_SESSION['userlevel']`